# How to add strong parameters to multiple attributes of a Devise model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, strong-parameters

I created a Devise model, and I added custom attributes. [This](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters) shows how to add strong parameters to one custom attribute, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to add strong parameters to multiple attributes.

This code works:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :attribute
end
```

but these all throw syntax errors:

```
#1
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :attribute :attribute2
end

#2
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :attribute, :attribute2
end

#3
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << (:attribute, :attribute2)
end

#4
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :attribute; :attribute2
end
```

What is the proper syntax for adding multiple attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scroll further down in your [linked documentation on strong parameters](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters), you should see how to permit multiple attributes:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |su| su.permit(:attribute; :attribute2) }
end
```